# Openshift can't rsh to pod with status of Crash Loop Back-off

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin

When I try to deploy I see...

> Error: Cannot find module 'express'

I am assuming this is because it isn't running `npm install` so I try to connect and do it manually but I get...

```
oc get pods
...
personal-ui-17-blah   0/1       CrashLoopBackOff   6          8m
oc rsh personal-ui-17-blah
error: unable to upgrade connection: container not found ("personal-ui")
```

How do I remote into a pod that is busted to fix it?

Comment: You can use ``oc debug``, but that isn't going to help because anything you install will be lost when the debug container exits. This is because the container file system isn't persistent. Do you have a ``package.json`` file in the top level directory of your repo listing packages that need to be installed. https://github.com/sclorg/s2i-nodejs-container/tree/master/8

Comment: Sorry I mean I think it was moving from Dev dependencies to reg.

Comment: See section on environment variables in doc I linked. There is one to set which mode it is running in.

Comment: Have you solved it out already?